# Is it possible to generate declarative macro tokens using quote?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I am writing some code to emit a declarative macro, and as you know, a decl macro is an `Ident` followed by a bang `!`, followed by a `Group` of non-Rust tokens. I want to generate this macro via code, but if I write `my_macro!` to the `TokenStream` via the `quote!` macro, it treats `my_macro` as an `Ident` and inserts a space between that and the `!`, making my emitted code (valid as pointed in the comments). I would still prefer to omit the whitespace. Is there a workaround this as I can feel that this problem will creep up again when I am writing the body of the decl macro.

PS: I have tried writing and `Ident::new("my_macro")` and a `Punct::new('!', Spacing::Joint)` but that didn't help.

Comment: I'm not sure the cause of your problem, but it is not by whitespace: `println ! ("hello world")` works just fine ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=926b538e310efdd61c1235f665d802da)).

Comment: I've done this kind of thing without trouble. Are you sure that your macro is in the right position?

Comment: @Yoric what do you mean by that? Do you mean `Ident` followed by `Punct` ?

Comment: What you're describing is a [function like macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html#function-like-procedural-macros), a [declarative macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html) is one defined by `macro_rules!`.

Comment: @RequireKeys I mean that I've written procedural macros that define a declarative macro and I didn't have any problem. However, I've always used a static name, so it might be different for you. Is the name of your macro dynamic?

Comment: @Yoric it's static for now. I resolved it by creating a `syn::Macro` instead and it took care of `to_tokens` avoiding the whitespace in between.

Answer (score -1):

The easy way is to create a `syn::Macro` and use its ToTokens implementation.